# In Django is it possible to specify separate `http` verbs with same urlpattern?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am creating a registration form in `Django 2.1`. In the typical examples people are using same views method both for showing forms and accepting `POST` request from forms like following:

In `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('auth/register', auth.register, name='register')
]
```

and in the view named `auth.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from blog_admin.forms import SignUpForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # do registration stuff...
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()

        return render(request, 'blog_admin/auth/register.html', {'form': form})
```

but I want to use separate method for showing the form and handling registration process and also want to use identical `urlpatterns` one with `GET` and one with `POST` functionality, like following:

in `urls.py`

```
    urlpatterns = [
        # can we limit it range, so that it only works for GET request
        path('auth/register', auth.show_registration_form, name='register_show'),
        # can we limit it range, so that it only works for POST request
        path('auth/register', auth.register, name='register')
    ]
```

and in the view named `auth.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from blog_admin.forms import SignUpForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


def show_registration_form(request):
    form = SignUpForm()

    return render(request, 'blog_admin/auth/register.html', {'form': form})

def register(request):
    # do registration stuff...
```

If need some more example from other frameworks, in `php` `Laravel` it would have been done by following:

```
Route::get('auth/register', ['as' => 'register_show', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@show_registration_form']);
Route::post('auth/register', ['as' => 'register', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@register']);
```

Comment: Typically one uses class-based views to separate the `GET`, `POST`, (and other methods).

Comment: See for example here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/intro/#handling-forms-with-class-based-views

Comment: Thanks, let me try :)